# View sorting becomes arbitrary with grouping field?

Tags: views

**The setup:**

A view that lists out nodes containing study abroad *Program* information. Its format is *Unformatted List*. There is a *Grouping field* of *Country* (which is a field on the *Program* content type). The list is sorted by *Country* (asc) and then *Program* title (asc).

There are exposed filters (via [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)) for a few of the fields from the *Program* content type... one of which is *Country*. These filters are exposed in a block that's included on the view page.

**The Problem:**

When you perform a search via the exposed filter block with multiple *Countries* selected, the sort order seems arbitrary. The grouping (by *Country*) works, but the *Countries* are listed out of order... not alphabetical asc or desc... just arbitrary.

Worth mentioning: any other search using any of the other exposed filters, but not selecting any *Country* values, works fine.

What's going on here? Why does sort get wacky when searching by *Country*... which, coincidentally or not, is also the grouping field?

---

[image: View settings]

Comment: Do you have the two sort criteria in the right order? With Country first and Program second? Or is Country is an entity reference to a node/taxonomy? I once had an odd case were sorting didn't work unless I used the title of the actual node via relationship. (It was always using the id for sorting for some reason and not the actual title.)

Comment: Sorting order is correct: 1. Country (asc), 2. Title (asc). The countries are not terms, they're just values in a select list (I forget why I set it up that way), so there are no relationships needed.

Comment: Taking into account all information you listed, it should be working. I have multiple views with grouped results where the groups are listed alphabetically, though never through a select list. Is the select list one with numerical index maybe? It would use the index for sorting then, not the title.

Comment: @Zuzuesque Ah... that's interesting... using the index instead of title... I hadn't thought of that. Just checked, the country name is both the key and value. Ex.: Argentina|Argentina; Brazil|Brazil.

Comment: @Zuzuesque Also, I should have mentioned, I am using Better Exposed Filters here. Just update the question to reflect that.

Comment: The Grouping by Country doesn't work after filtering.. Choose Ecuador, France and Germany for example. It goes France>Germany>France>Ecuador etc. Upload a screenshot of your view and the settings page for the list.

Comment: @NiallMurphy Uploaded screenshot... AND in doing so, I think I figured it out. I unchecked "Reduce Duplicates" in the Country exposed filter and I think it's working as expected. Still testing to be sure. Yeesh...

Comment: Yep, I can see that it's fixed already. Good stuff.. There seems to be a maximum number of countries that you can select though.. Minor thing but Argentina > Uganda works but Argentina > United Kingdom doesn't.


So someone who wants to check every country except the US for example, can't. And take out "multiple countries" at the end.

Comment: @NiallMurphy That's odd... I can select all countries without a problem. I'll look into it. "Multiple Countries" is actually a Country value. Students might want to search only for programs that span multiple countries. It's weird, I know.

Comment: Now it's working.. Strange. I tried it like five times before trying to see a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that disabling "Reduce duplicates" on the exposed filter of the grouping field will bring the sort back in order. So, in this case, unchecking "Reduce duplicates" on the exposed filter, Country (which is also the grouping field) did the trick.

[image: settings screen]

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why reducing duplicates was breaking the sort order. For completeness, I'd like to update the answer with an explanation if anyone has one... or I'd be happy to concede to a more thorough answer. (Funny that I found the answer myself only after starting a bounty. Well, at least it's fixed!)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for answering your own question.. I wish more people would!